# importing an entire folder of .py files into google colab

Tags: python, upload, google-colaboratory

I have a folder of . py files(a package made by me) which i have uploaded into my google drive.

I have mounted my google drive in colab but I still can not import the folder in my notebook as i do in my pc.

I know how to upload a single .py file into google colab and import it into my code, but i have no idea about how to upload a folder of .py files and import it in notebook and this is what i need to do.

This is the code i used to mount drive:

> from google.colab import drive
>
> drive.mount('/content/drive')
>
> !ls 'drive/My Drive'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found how to do it. 
after uploading all modules and packages into the directory which my notebook file is in, I changed colab's directory from "/content" to this directory and then i simply imported the modules and packages(folder of .py files) into my code